# Post Requests from python Issue

Tags: python, json

I have been doing a lot of reading on this website regarding post requests from Python to an API. But despite all the recommendations to using the `json` library within Python, I still cant quite get my head around it.

My current predicament is that I need to make an API call, grab certain fields and post them to another API.

An example of the information i receive from my initial API request:

```
    {
    "metadata": {
        "configurationVersions": [
            3
        ],
        "clusterVersion": "1.174.168.20190814-173650"
    },
    "id": "5c1547a6-61ca-4dc3-8971-ec8d2f542592",
    "name": "Registration",
    "enabled": false,
    "dataType": "STRING",
    "dataSources": [
        {
            "enabled": true,
            "source": "POST_PARAMETER",
            "valueProcessing": {
                "splitAt": "",
                "trim": false
                },
                "parameterName": "f=register",
                "scope": {
                "tagOfProcessGroup": "Production"
            }
        }
    ],
    "normalization": "ORIGINAL",
    "aggregation": "FIRST",
    "confidential": true,
    "skipPersonalDataMasking": true
}
```

After this call, I extract the data in the following way:

```
def ReqOutput(output):
    x=""
    out = ()
    inReq = ["name","enabled","dataType","dataSources","normalization","aggregation","confidential","skipPersonalDataMasking"]
    for i in output.items():
        for item in inReq:
            if item in i:
                x = x + str(i)
                out=out + i
    return json.dumps(out)
```

As recommended in other threads, I used to `json.dumps` method to convert my python tuple to JSON. However, I feel like it is not working as intended

Pre `json.dumps` output:

```
'name', 'Registration', 'enabled', False, 'dataType', 'STRING', 'dataSources', [{'enabled': True, 'source': 'POST_PARAMETER', 'valueProcessing': {'splitAt': '', 'trim': False}, 'parameterName': 'f=register', 'scope': {'tagOfProcessGroup': 'Production'}}], 'normalization', 'ORIGINAL', 'aggregation', 'FIRST', 'confidential', True, 'skipPersonalDataMasking', True)
```

Post `json.dumps` output:

```
["name", "Registration", "enabled", false, "dataType", "STRING", "dataSources", [{"enabled": true, "source": "POST_PARAMETER", "valueProcessing": {"splitAt": "", "trim": false}, "parameterName": "f=register", "scope": {"tagOfProcessGroup": "Production"}}], "normalization", "ORIGINAL", "aggregation", "FIRST", "confidential", true, "skipPersonalDataMasking", true]
```

I then try and POST this to another API using:

```
def PostRequest (data):
postURL = "XXXX"
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(postURL,data = data,headers = headers)
print(r.text)
```

Where I am finally met with the error:

```
{"error":{"code":400,"message":"Could not map JSON at '' near line 1 column 1"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting rid of the `for` loops in favor of a dict comprehension:

```
def ReqOutput(output):
    inReq = ["name","enabled","dataType","dataSources","normalization","aggregation","confidential","skipPersonalDataMasking"]
    out = {output: val for output, val in output.items() if output in inReq}
    return json.dumps(out)
```

This is more readable and will always give you a `dict` with attributes from `output` that are in `inReq`. The reason your `JSON` looks like that is because serializing a `tuple` will give you an `Array`-like structure. If what you want is an `Object` structure, you should serialize a `dict`-like object.

Comment: Thank you so much! That has fixed my issue